# Is it possible to make own "binance bridge" with smart cntract

Tags: erc-20, bsc

Hay everyone
I was wondering, is it possible to make a smart contract that can change your tokens network for example from erc-20 to bsc?
(Smothering like binance bridge)
I would be glad if enlightening me?!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't make it with just smart contracts. Contracts are deterministic, which means they can't access outside resources directly.

You will need some sort of off-chain functionality, which acts as the bridge. So you need contracts at both ends of the bridge and the actual bridge which listens to events in the contracts to call the other end of the bridge.